# keyerror the name "import/Placeholder" refers to an operation not in the graph

Tags: python, tensorflow

So I was trying to run the Tensorflow retraining for the Inception V3 model, and no matter what I tried, running the label_image command didn't work.

I tried resetting the values as such:

```
input_height = 299
input_width = 299
input_mean = 0
input_std = 299
input_layer = "input"
output_layer = "final_result"
```

and like so:

```
input_height = 299
input_width = 299
input_mean = 0
input_std = 299
input_layer = "Mul"
output_layer = "final_result"
```

the command

```
python label_image.py --graph=output_graph.pb --labels=output_labels.txt --output_layer=final_result --input_layer=Placeholder --image=fox.png
```

yields the error in the title.

changing the command to:

```
python label_image.py --graph=output_graph.pb     --labels=output_labels.txt --output_layer=final_result --input_layer=input --image=fox.png
```

gives the same error but with 'import/input'

Command as it is now:

```
python label_image.py --graph=output_graph.pb --labels=output_labels.txt --output_layer=final_result --image=fox.png
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "label_image.py", line 128, in <module>
    input_operation = graph.get_operation_by_name(input_name)
  File "C:\Users\Phil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\t
ensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 3606, in get_operation_by_name
    return self.as_graph_element(name, allow_tensor=False, allow_operation=True)

  File "C:\Users\Phil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\t
ensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 3478, in as_graph_element
    return self._as_graph_element_locked(obj, allow_tensor, allow_operation)
  File "C:\Users\Phil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\t
ensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 3538, in _as_graph_element_locked
    "graph." % repr(name))
KeyError: "The name 'import/input' refers to an Operation not in the graph."
```

Comment: Try 'input' as the input layer. Also, the commands you show have incorrect or missing label parameter.

Comment: My bad, I didn't write the command right. I fixed it. The same issue still persists.